# trying to change twitter button style like facebook

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I have included facebook like button in my website and i used `i frame` 
and here is my facebook like button code

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;width&amp;layout=box_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=65" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;height:65px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

This style is good its square and fix in my page in same maner i tried to apply `twitter` and `google+` here i dont get the same style as facebook like
[image]

i need to apply same style like facebook

```
<iframe                             src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets/follow_button.html?screen_name=twitterapi"
                                    style="width: 300px; height: 20px;"
                                    allowtransparency="true"
                                    frameborder="0"
                                    scrolling="no">
                                </iframe>
                                <iframe src="https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?bsv&amp;size=medium&amp;hl=en-US&amp;url=http://test.com/&amp;parent=http://test.com/" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;height:65px;" title="+1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this source : https://dev.twitter.com/web/overview/css (twitter)

And this one : https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/ (google +)

---

There are some examples and styles generators how to customize this plugins